# Why is my localStorage emptied in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have an issue with localStorage in Firefox and existing posts don't solve this issue. This is what I do:

I have a local storage "dem" (works). And I run through this flow:

- take data from "dem" --> on page 1: check whether some condition (other than "dem"-related) is met
- **if yes** --> go to page 2 ---> then go to page 3 (use "dem" here) THIS WORKS
- **if not** --> go back to page 1 again and begin again

If the latter happens, I have an empty localStorage on page 3. Only then and only in Firefox (v 33.0).

The command I use are to get the items in "dem":

```
 dem = window.localStorage.getItem("dem").split(",")
```

I can't figure out why it breaks only after the page order is repeated. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any console error? Try looking for them in the Firefox Dev Tools

Comment: This is the error: `TypeError: window.localStorage.getItem(...) is null` and I just can't understand why the localStorage is emptied.

Comment: This is going the be a logic error, so we're going to need to see the logic to diagnose it.

Comment: Did you mention firefox because you've tested all other browsers? or because you're only testing firefox.

Comment: I tested all others and it works there. I now experimented with the privacy settings. If I never allow the browser history to be saved, it clears the localstorage apparently (oddly enough not the sessionStorage). Could that be?

Comment: You can download older and portable versions of Firefox in "portableapps" maybe you can try on a fresh browser and older FF versions